# Chunks and functions - fig.height problem with plots

Tags: r, function, r-markdown, chunks

I have a issue, which I can't avoid. So, I have two chunks which they contain functions. These functions generate plots. My problem is that I want two plots with different size of height. How can I avoid these problems? This is a simple example of this problem:

````
```{r setup, fig.height= 2}

plot1 <- function(cars) {

summary(cars)

plot(cars$dist,cars$speed)

}
```

```{r cars, fig.height= 7}

plot2 <- function(x) {

x <- rnorm (100)

hist(x)

}

```

```{r pressure}

 plot1(cars)
 plot2(x)

```
````

This code give me a two plots of default size (size from *pressure* chunk) but I want size from the *setup* and *cars* chunks, so 2 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

The chunk setting applies to the current chunk, not to code that was defined in it, so it's the setting on the third chunk that matters.  The settings on the first two chunks are irrelevant, because those chunks don't do any plotting.

Generally speaking it is not possible to change the value of a chunk option from the code in the chunk:  some options are used before the code is executed, and `fig.height` is one that can't be changed.

The way to get what you want is to put the `plot1()` and `plot2()` calls in different chunks.

Comment: I thought so... Ok, maybe I change my code. Thanks.